# in selenium can't switch handle new popup layer

Tags: python, selenium

this is html part. it appear new layer popup in widows.

```
<div style="top: 20px;" id="appInstallSuggestLayer" class="ly_prm_app">
    <div class="prm_app_wrap">
        <div class="prm_app_header">
            <strong class="blind">today news</strong>
```

but, it is no iframe name in source and, no windows alert and,

no new windows pop up.

it appear new layer popup over 'mainframe' in browser, but iframe name is no.

so I can't hadle

what can I handle this layer popup??

Comment: do you mean iframe exists but it's not contain name attribute. Right??

Comment: it appear new layer popup over webpage. but it is no iframe name... it is only '<div class="prm_app_wrap">'  . it is new popup , but it is no frame...

Comment: What do you mean by no iframe name??? Do you mean only iframe name or whole iframe element??

Comment: usually layer pop up have below frame and frame name. but it is no frame,frame name.

Comment: Ok then try to wait until it's visible.. try provided answer and let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `frame` or `iframe` no need to switch anywhere just need to implement  `WebDriverWait` to wait until popup visible as below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
pop_up = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'prm_app_wrap')))
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: if close layer popup,  add line ' pop_up.close()'?

Comment: No, you need to find close button and click on it..:)